# Is there a tool that generates a PDF version of a transaction?

Tags: transactions, etherscan

Etherscan provides a nice UI for viewing what happened in an Ethereum transaction, including internal contract state updates.

Is there a tool or an API that takes an Etherscan link, or an Ethereum transaction hash, and returns a PDF document?